# An optimization problem in finite groups

Tags: co.combinatorics, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group, say, of order $n$. I ran into the following problem (where $|A|$ denotes the cardinality of a set $A$):

*To determine the minimum of $|A|+|B|$ for sets $A, B \subset G$ such that $A^{-1} \cdot B = G$.*

Specifically, is this minimum the same as the minimum of sums $u+v$ for positive integers $u, v$ with $u \cdot v \ge n$?

In the latter (purely numerical) problem, one finds that the largest of $u, v$ (say, $u$) is $\lceil \sqrt{n} \rceil$, the other one being $v = \lceil \frac{n}{u} \rceil$.   (or vice versa). Seen as functions of $n$, solutions $u, v$ can be rather "irregular" and probably obstruct attempts for a proof by induction on $n$.

The two minima are seen to be equal if $G = \mathbb Z / n \mathbb Z$. I verified with Maple that the same goes for Dihedral groups of order $\le 16$. With many examples available now for the sets $A, B$, I still do not see a pattern that is provably decisive. The equation $A^{-1} \cdot B = G$ has this "geometric" interpretation: no translation $A \cdot g$ of $A$ can be disjoint with $B$.

My question derives from a geometric problem (largely solved in the mean time) to find conditions on the size of (two or more) subsets of the regular $n$-gon (essentially, $\mathbb Z / n \mathbb Z$) ensuring that the sets can be "rotated apart". An affirmative answer to my question implies that some critical boundary (called "spaghetti boundary") simply carries over from $\mathbb Z / n \mathbb Z$ to any finite group of order $n$.

The two minima may fail to be the same for all groups of order $n$. In that case, groups $G$ with a larger minimum may be of interest for use as a replacement of $\mathbb Z / n \mathbb Z$ in shuffled equi-$n$-squares: the key result, mentioned in my question "A toroidal version of Rubik's cube: how many shuffles?", has somewhat better chances to apply in the replacement square.

Comment: As you probably realise, this minimum is certianly at most ${\rm min}( d+\frac{n}{d})$  such that $G$ has a subgroup of order $d$ ( taking $A$ to be a subgroup of order $d$ and $B$ to be a set of right coset representatives for that subgroup).

Comment: In a number of cases this gives a good or even accurate value, e.g., for n=16 you get the accurate value of 4+4=8 and for n=44 you get 4+11=15 which is 1 too large. For groups of prime order, or having distinct prime factors far from the "middle" $\sqrt{n}$  the difference can become significant.

Comment: I personally doubt this could be true. Can you find an example of $\lvert A \rvert + \lvert B \rvert = 11$ for $G = (\mathbb{Z}/3)^3$?

Comment: On the other hand, I think a naive probabilistic argument gives an example of $\lvert A \rvert + \lvert B \rvert = O(\sqrt{n \log n})$.

Comment: @Marcel Van de Vel: Your analysis of the "purely numerical problem" is wrong. E.g. for $n=24$ the minimal sum is $10 = 4 + 6 = 5 + 5$, so in this case there are more than one optimal $(u,v)$ up to permutation (moreover $6 \neq \lceil \sqrt{n} \rceil$ here).

Comment: @js21: you are right, I should have said that a different pair $(x,y)$ has $x \cdot y < u \cdot v$. For $n = 24$ we have $u = 5 = v$ as the computed numerical solution. Quite often, $u \cdot v > n$ so that $(x,y) \ge n$ is still possible. I withdraw that statement.

Comment: @Dongryul Kim: I've done some searching in Maple on $(\mathbb{Z} / 3)^3$, so far without success. It can be assumed that $A, B$ both contain the neutral element. That is not much of a restriction...

Answer (score 6):

If $A,B\subseteq G$ satisfy $A^{-1}\cdot B=G$ and $|A|+|B|<K\sqrt{|G|}$ for some absolute constant $K$, then for the set $S:=A^{-1}\cup B$ we have $S\cdot S=G$ and $|S|<2K\sqrt{|G|}$. Thus, if you could show the existence of such $A$ and $B$ for any finite group $G$, this would establish the [Rohrbach Conjecture](https://mathoverflow.net/q/270913). Conversely, if the conjecture is true, then you can find $S\subseteq G$ with $|S|<K\sqrt{|G|}$ and $S\cdot S=G$ and define $A:=S^{-1}$ and $B:=S$ to get $A^{-1}\cdot B=G$ and $|A|+|B|<2K\sqrt{|G|}$.

The bottom line is, your question is equivalent to an open, 80-year-old conjecture.

Comment: Amazing. I never heard of Rohrbach's conjecture before (I'm not an expert in group theory).  Some time ago I gave a lecture on shuffled equi-$n$-squares. One algebraist in the audience asked me afterwards "can you do it with finite groups too"? That's how I came to this topic.   I'll take a closer look at the conjecture.

Comment: The statement, that the minimum of $|A|+|B|$ for $A^{-1} \cdot B = G$ equals the minimum of $u+v$ for $u \cdot v \ge n$  and $n$ the order of $G$, is properly stronger than the Rohrbach conjecture. Hence failure of the former does not necessarily cause failure of the latter.

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure how many groups have this property ( the group $A_{5}$ does, for example), and it gives rather a weak bound, but I mention a situation where neither $A$ nor $B$ need be a subgroup (in case others find it suggestive).

Let $G$ be a finite group of even order in which every element is strongly real ( that is, either an involution, or a product of two involutions). Let $A = B = I(G) = \{ x \in G :x^{2} = 1 \}.$ Then $A^{-1}B = G$  and $|A| + |B| = 2|I(G)|.$

The cardinality of $I(G)$ can be calculated fairly easily by character theory. We let ${\rm Irr}(G)$ denote the set of complex irreducible characters of $G$, and for $\chi \in {\rm Irr}(G),$ let $\nu(\chi)$ denote the Frobenius-Schur indicator of $\chi$. Then $\nu(\chi) \in \{0,1,-1 \}$ and $\nu(\chi) = \frac{1}{|G|} \sum_{g \in G} \chi(g^{2}).$ In fact, the fact that every element of $G$ is strongly real implies that $\nu(\chi) \neq 0$ for each $\chi \in {\rm Irr}(G).$

The cardinality $|I(G)|$ is equal to $\sum_{ \chi \in {\rm Irr}(G) } \nu(\chi) \chi(1).$ The Cauchy-Schwartz inequality impies that $|I(G)| \leq \sqrt{k(G)|G|},$ where $k(G)$ is the number of irreducible characters of $G$.

Later edit: all simple groups ${\rm SL}(2,2^{n})$ with $n >1$ have this property, and for such $G$ we have $|I(G)| = 2^{2n},$ giving $2|I(G)|$ very close to $2|G|^{\frac{2}{3}}.$

Comment: The bound is indeed rather weak (giving 20 for $A_5$) but it's a nice observation. I learned from Maple's output (producing many pairs $A, B$ for each inspected dihedral group) that sets at the minimum are often quite "irregular". At least, there seems to be no dominating pattern.

Comment: I think this gives $2(1+3+3 + 4+5) = 32$ for $A_{5},$ to be pedantic, which is even worse..